# How can I post on a friends wall using facebook SDK c#

Tags: c#, winforms, facebook

Can we post pictures/videos or links on friends wall using facebook SDK c#?
i am using it in winforms .I am using this SDK
https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk

Comment: why close ?is there anything wrong in the question if yes then point it out rather than closing it out

Comment: I think its a reasonable question. Maybe better phrased as "How can I post on a friends wall...".

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you choose that specific SDK? Shouldn't your question really be "What .NET Facebook SDK allows for posting on a friend's wall and has good documentation?"

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395

Comment: @kenny - ah, ok, looks like it's the official SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have your application user grant stream_publish extended permissions then you may use the Graph API to publish to friends' streams.

Comment: I didn't use this SDK (it has very poor functionality). The best .NET SDK for Facebook I ever seen is "Facebook C# SDK", you can download it here: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ There are also some samples there.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void PostToWall(string wallPost, string friendId)
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient(Globals.AccessToken);
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
    parameters["message"] = wallPost;
    fb.PostAsync(String.Format("{0}/feed", friendId), parameters);
}
```

If you want to post it to the wall of the user logged in, use:

```
fb.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use PostTaskAsync instead of obsolete PostAsync method of FacebookClient. The parameters remain the same.